# Why do I get CORS errors on my machine when the code is correct?

Tags: .net, cors

I am getting CORS errors when running an application on my machine, however co-workers do not when running the exact same code.

Here is my setup: a React frontend running on `https://localhost:1234`. It needs to talk to an dotnet 6 api running on port `https://localhost:7047`. For simplicity, I'm just trying to allow any origin so this what my `Program.cs` looks like in the api:

```
// configuring the services up here 
// but it is fairly simple

var app = builder.Build();

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseCors(options =>
{
    options.AllowAnyOrigin()
        .AllowAnyMethod()
        .AllowAnyHeader();
});

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

This is FireFox's error from the console:

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://localhost:7047/v1/login. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed). Status code: (null).

error TypeError: NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource. consola.browser.js:1:8898
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://localhost:7047/v1/login. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed). Status code: (null).
```

I know the code works because the *same* code runs (without CORS errors) on my team-mates computers on the same ports and browsers - but it doesn't work on *my* machine!

Has anyone experienced this or have any insight?

Comment: [A helpful guide to debugging CORS issues](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS/Errors)

Answer (score 0):

This works for me. You need to register CORS first and then enable that in middleware . Please note this is for ASP.NET Core 6:

```
builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy(name: MyAllowSpecificOrigins,
                      builder =>
                      {
                          builder.WithOrigins("http://example.com",
                                              "http://www.contoso.com");
                      });
});

// services.AddResponseCaching();

builder.Services.AddControllers();

var app = builder.Build();
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseRouting();

app.UseCors(MyAllowSpecificOrigins);

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

If you are using for ASP.NET 3.1 and 5.0, you can use  ConfigureServices method to configure CORS

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddCors(o => o.AddPolicy("MyPolicy", builder =>
    {
        builder.WithOrigins("http://example.com")
               .AllowAnyMethod()
               .AllowAnyHeader();
    }));

    // ...
}
```

In the Configure method you can just enable it

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
{
    app.UseCors("MyPolicy");

    // ...

    // This should always be called last to ensure that
    // middleware is registered in the correct order.
    app.UseMvc();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for responding @Amit. I've tried that with the same results. The big issue here is that the above code works on other people's computers, just not mine lol.

Comment: If you're using UseHttpsRedirection, make your app is calling the https URL.